# Retrofit kotlin, как сделать изменяемый запрос

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

У меня есть приложение с фильмами, они содержаться в recyclerview, стартовый фрагмент заполняется популярными фильмами, по клику на itemview нужно сделать запрос с id фильма. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как сделать изменяемый запрос в retrofit и как передать в него id

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/retrofit2/query-path-parameters/